# How can I mix html and svg in an elm view?

Tags: elm

I'm attempting to add a control to turn the subscription on and off in the [elm time example](http://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/effects/time.html). The problem is that I can't get html and svg to coexist in the view.

So far, I have this for the view:

```
import Html exposing (Html)
import Html.App as Html
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Svg exposing (..)
import Svg.Attributes exposing (..)
import Time exposing (Time, second)

-- MODEL, UPDATE and SUBSCRIPTION removed for brevity

-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  Html.div []
    [ Html.p [] [ text "hello world" ]
    , clock
    ]

clock : Model -> Html msg
clock model =
  let
    angle =
      turns (Time.inMinutes model.time)

    handX =
      toString (50 + 40 * cos angle)

    handY =
      toString (50 + 40 * sin angle)
  in
    svg [ viewBox "0 0 100 100", Svg.Attributes.width "300px" ]
      [ circle [ cx "50", cy "50", r "45", fill "#0B79CE" ] []
      , line [ x1 "50", y1 "50", x2 handX, y2 handY, stroke "#023963" ] []
      ]
```

However, I get the following message when I try to transpile:

```
Detected errors in 1 module.
==================================== ERRORS ====================================



-- TYPE MISMATCH ------------------------------------------ examples/6-clock.elm

The 1st and 2nd elements are different types of values.

70|     [ Html.p [] [ text "hello world" ]
71|>    , clock
72|     ]

The 1st element has this type:

    VirtualDom.Node a

But the 2nd is:

    Model -> Html a

Hint: All elements should be the same type of value so that we can iterate
through the list without running into unexpected values.
```

In addition to fixing the error, is there a way to fix the problem of not having to prepend `Html` to all the html elements? e.g. `Html.div` as opposed to the usual `div`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`clock` is a function that receives a `Model` and returns some `Html`.

As the compiler is telling you, you'll need to have an `Html` element inside your `view`. It should be enough to pass the `model` to the `clock` function, like

```
view model =
  Html.div []
    [ Html.p [] [ text "hello world" ]
    , clock model
    ]
```

To be able to use directly `div` instead of `Html.div` you could import their definition using

```
import Html exposing (Html, div, p)
```

and so on, or, if you want to import all the `Html` package

```
import Html exposing (..)
```